# Pointer in typedef struct confusion

Tags: c, pointers, struct, typedef

I am trying to define a typedef struct as follows:

```
typedef struct node{
    int keys[2*MIN_DEGREE-1];
    struct node* child[2*MIN_DEGREE];
    int numkeys;
    int isleaf;
} BNODE,*BNODEPTR;
```

Instead of using `struct node* child[2*MIN_DEGREE]` why can't I declare the struct as follows:

```
typedef struct node{
    int keys[2*MIN_DEGREE-1];
    BNODEPTR child[2*MIN_DEGREE];
    int numkeys;
    int isleaf;
} BNODE,*BNODEPTR;
```

I am little confused as to how the compiler resolves structs that has nested pointers to the same type. It will be great somebody helps me clear this up.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `BNODEPTR` in the body of the structure like that because it either doesn't exist as a type at all until after the definition after the close brace of the structure body, or (worse) it refers to a different type altogether<sup>*</sup>.

You could use:

```
typedef struct node BNODE, *BNODEPTR;

struct node
{
    int keys[2*MIN_DEGREE-1];
    BNODEPTR child[2*MIN_DEGREE];
    int numkeys;
    int isleaf;
};
```

And there's another whole argument that says `BNODEPTR` is evil and you should only use `BNODE` and `BNODE *`, but that's a style issue, not a technical one.

Were it my code, it would probably be more like:

```
typedef struct Node Node;

struct Node
{
    int   keys[2*MIN_DEGREE-1];
    Node *child[2*MIN_DEGREE];
    int   numkeys;
    int   isleaf;
};
```

In C++, the rules are slightly different and you would not need the `typedef` line (so `Node` would be known as a type from the open brace).

<sup>* This can only happen if the original `BNODEPTR` is defined at an outer scope and this one appears inside a function, but when it happens, it is really confusing!</sup>

Answer (score 1):

> Instead of using `struct node* child[2*MIN_DEGREE]` why can't I declare
>   the struct as follows: `BNODEPTR child[2*MIN_DEGREE];`?

At that point, compiler (yet) does not know what the symbol `BNODEPTR` is.